# start and end angle of UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, angle, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have coded as below for half circle in iOS using **UIBezierPath** and **CAShapeLayer**.

```
 clockWiseLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI_2;
CGFloat endAngle = M_PI + M_PI_2;

CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame)/2.0f + 30;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame)/2.0f +50;
CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(width, height);

float radius = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame)/2+10;

clockWiseLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint
                                                    radius:radius
                                                startAngle:startAngle
                                                  endAngle:endAngle
                                                 clockwise:YES].CGPath;

clockWiseLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

clockWiseLayer.strokeStart = 0.0f;
clockWiseLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5f;

clockWiseLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
clockWiseLayer.borderWidth = 5.0f;

clockWiseLayer.shouldRasterize = NO;
[self.layer addSublayer:clockWiseLayer];
```

This results as below.

[image]

I want this blue half circle on the opposite side of the World Globe.

It is half Circle, but I want it on the other side, also CounterClockWise.

I am unable to set start and end angle for that, while **clockwise:NO**.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just start from M_PI_2 and end M_PI_2 + M_PI ?

Comment: Yes I did, no use. its coming not exactly opposite.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am **unable** to set start and end angle for that, while clockwise:NO" It does not draw a half circle? It crashes? something else?

Comment: It is not crashing, but it not showing result as I am expecting. If I say NO to clockwise it will be astonished (hide from view) in same start and end angle @Avt

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Check documentation for coordinates:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yJo6.png

[image]

Y-Axis is reversed compared to standard coordinate system in mathematics.

You should draw from 1/2*PI (bottom anchor) to 3/2*PI (top anchor) and then you set strokeStart to 0.0f and strokeEnd to 1.0f (so it fills whole path).

Working code using iOS constants:

```
CGFloat startAngle = M_PI_2;
CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + M_PI;
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame)/2.0f;
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(imageView.frame)/2.0f;
CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(width, height);
float radius = CGRectGetWidth(imageView.frame)/2+10;
CAShapeLayer* clockWiseLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
clockWiseLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint
                                                     radius:radius
                                                 startAngle:startAngle
                                                   endAngle:endAngle
                                                  clockwise:YES].CGPath;

clockWiseLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
clockWiseLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

clockWiseLayer.strokeStart = 0.0f;
clockWiseLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0f;

clockWiseLayer.lineWidth = 2.0f;
clockWiseLayer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
[self.layer addSublayer:clockWiseLayer];
```

Comment: If I want to move a circle from Top to top anticlockwise , what should be the start and end Angle. Please help

Comment: @DilipTiwari all you need to do is to use different startAngle and endAngle - rest stays the same. endAngle will be startAngle + 2*M_PI, startAngle is as explained above M_PI+M_PI_2.

Answer (score 7):

You start from top of the circle with `-M_PI_2` and end at `M_PI + M_PI_2` (if you want to have full circle and limit it using `strokeEnd`, `strokeStart`). Then set the circle path to draw from half of the end of the path (left side of image) instead from beginning to half (right side of the image)

```
CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI_2;
CGFloat endAngle = M_PI + M_PI_2;

clockWiseLayer.strokeStart = .5f;
clockWiseLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have played with `bezierPathWithArcCenter` and it works quite strange if `clockwise = NO`. But if you want to create an circle bezier path with conterclockwise direction you can create a clockwise path and then revert it with [bezierPathByReversingPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathByReversingPath)

> A new path object with the same path shape but for which the path has been created in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

This function can help to set the start and end position of arc in the circle.

```
func fillProgress(from currentValue: Double, to finalValue: Double, with duration: TimeInterval) {
    let startAngle = CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2)
    let completionPercentage = currentValue / Double(finalValue)
    let endAngle = startAngle + (2 * .pi * completionPercentage)
    
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(
        arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0),
        radius: frame.width / 2 - circleLineWidth / 2,
        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: endAngle,
        clockwise: true
    )
    
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleLayer.lineCap = .square
    circleLayer.lineWidth = circleLineWidth
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

    let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    progressLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.lineCap = .square
    progressLayer.lineWidth = circleLineWidth
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    progressLayer.strokeColor = R.color.color_82C9AD()?.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    
    // Animate
    let circularProgressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    circularProgressAnimation.duration = duration
    circularProgressAnimation.toValue = 1.0
    circularProgressAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    circularProgressAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    progressLayer.add(circularProgressAnimation, forKey: "progressAnim")
}
```

}

Here `circleLineWidth` can have custom values as how bold the arc you need. `finalValue` is the value representing the whole circle means 360 degrees. `currentValue` is the value out of `finalValue`.

Arc will be drawn from zero (Top) to `currentValue`